# Use Where on generic cache based on MemoryCache

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic cache:

```
public class Cache<T>
{
    private readonly MemoryCache memoryCache;

    public Cache(string name)
    {
        memoryCache = new MemoryCache(name);
    }

    //public IEnumerable<T> Where(....) { }
}
```

And is used as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

Cache<User> users = new Cache<User>("users");
```

How can I implement `Where` so that I can do something like:

```
users.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement `IEnumerable<T>` and you will get all the functionality that you want. Like this:

```
public class Cache<T>:IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public Cache(string name)
    {
        _memoryCache = new MemoryCache(name);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _memoryCache.Select(p=>p.Value).OfType<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remember that the simplest solution is not always best. If you have a lot of records, this method gets them all from the cache and iterates through them. Without details on how you implement the insertion of elements I cannot give you a working example, but try to think of ways of getting just a subset of cached elements, then look through them.